Is the blue Weller WECP-20 ESD safe?
There are two Weller WECP-20 soldering stations. One blue and one black.
The black one has a label "ESD SAFE" and the blue have no ESD label at all. But is the blue Weller WECP-20 still ESD safe?
I mean, they have the same functionality and plastic. Same soldering iron.
So what's the difference?

TL;DR; I have a sneaking suspicion it's just a change in branding colours or regional differences and not actually a functional difference in ESD capabilities.

For a start there doesn't seem to be an alternative part number for the black vs blue ones. The datasheet does list two different parts, but doesn't specify list colours. The only difference between the two parts in the datasheet is one uses encoders for temperature selection while the other uses a variable control. Both show the same ESD handling capabilities.

Pictures of both coloured items show both have the 4mm banana jack which provides the equipotential bonding point to both the tip and body of the soldering iron - note that both show the diagram of earth and tip above the jack.
You can use the bonding point to attach to your workbench or an ESD mat or workpiece holder to get everything to the same potential and remove risk of ESD.
From the datasheet:


There is a bit there about an option for changing the bonding from a 0R link to a 120kOhm filter by removing a factory installed resistor. It is theoretically possible that could be a difference between the two versions, but given there is no alternative part number I doubt it.

I would guess it has to do with the exposed plastic bits being static-dissipative so they can't hold much of a charge for long, but I see
nothing in the datasheets that confirms that is exactly what it means.
So they would not be the same.
This is similar to the static-dissipative Xcelite cutters with black handles vs. colorful-handled ones sold for non-electronic purposes.

According to the blue Weller data sheet. They claims that you can mount some kind of ESD button. I don't know what it's for.

@euraad the ESD "button" is basically just a converter from banana jack to the button snap connectors you find on ESD wristbands as shown on page 45 of the datasheet.
